# Android:layout_toLeftOf ~ No resource found

Tags: android, android-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pickerDialog_title"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD!!" />
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/pickerDialog_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pickerDialog_title" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickerDialog_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pickerDialog_selector"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/pickerDialog_set" //Cannot find @id/pickerDialog_set
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Cancel" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickerDialog_set" //Here it is
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pickerDialog_selector"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pickerDialog_cancel"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Set" />
</merge>
```

`No resource found that matches the given name (at layout_toLeftOf with value @id/pickerDialog_set`

It was my understanding that, `android:id` should be prefixed as `@+id/`, with reference made to the view to be prefixed as `@id/`

**How do i reference ids correctly?**

Comment: Move the last button above your Button with id "pickerDialog_cancel" and it will then be able to find the id.

Comment: Because that id isn't created yet. Move the last button **before** the referring one. `How do i reference ids correctly?` Top-Down. So, set the referred ids **before** the referring ones.

Comment: that id does not exist, as the file is read from top to bottom. refer to it as `@+id...` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the order of the Button that is toLeftOf the one this one button, because you can not use an id, before it is created. Your code should looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pickerDialog_title"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD!!" />
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/pickerDialog_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pickerDialog_title" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickerDialog_set" //Here it is
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pickerDialog_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Set" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickerDialog_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pickerDialog_selector"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/pickerDialog_set" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Cancel" />
 </merge>
```

and remove the `android:layout_toRightOf` of the `pickerDialog_set` Button like I did in the code above

Answer (score 0):

Try this `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pickerDialog_set"`.

Comment: Why negative votes? It is working perfectly. Just try.

Comment: You made a typo. Place the "+" behind the "@". But I don't get those downvotes, too.

Comment: Och, sorry, my fault.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the sign "+" when you add the id for the first time in your layout (from top to bottom).
So this should do the trick:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pickerDialog_set"
```